# Не удается прочитать строковый ресурс из native code .dll в Visual Studio старше 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Странная проблема с Visual Studio.
Есть прога на C#, которой надо получать некоторые строковые ресурсы из обычной нативной .dll-библиотеки. В сильно сокращенном виде смысл кода примерно такой:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string filename);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uId, out StringBuilder buffer, int bufferMax);

//...

IntPtr _libPtr = LoadLibrary(filename);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
LoadString(_libPtr, id, out sb, 0);
return sb.ToString();
```

В Visual Studio 2010 и младше этот код отлично работает, но в 2012 и старше происходит что-то странное: на вызове LoadString(...) дебаг просто завершается без выдачи каких-либо ошибок — так, как будто бы прога просто отработала. Проверено на одном и том же проекте с одними и теми же данными, и даже создавался тестовый проект с одной этой функцией — поведение сохраняется. Проверено в VS 2012, 2013, 2015.
Подозреваю, что есть какая-то потенциально влияющая настройка, но так и не удалось ничего подобного найти ни в гугле, ни сравнением конфигураций...

Comment: Попробуйте понизить версию .net фреймворка до <=4.0

Comment: @Bezarius  .net вовсех случаях был 4.0.
Удалось обойти, заменив на вот такое:
`[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uId, out IntPtr buffer, int bufferMax);
IntPtr resource;
var length = LoadString(_libPtr, id, out resource, 0);
return length == 0 ? null : Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(resource, length);`